# How to get previous Git Installers for Windows

Tags: git

I am new to Git, I just want to start with Git. I searched so many sites, blogs and even the Git site also but it is showing only the latest version (2.10.0), but I need Git version 1.9.5 only for my project.

And also give the steps to install and run it.

Comment: Why would you want to use old, obsolete version?

Comment: Thanks for fast response @ 1615903. i am working with aws code commit,so my leads suggest me to download that version only.

Comment: Though politeness is appreciated, things like _"thanks in advance"_ or usual email form sign offs are discouraged. Please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page.

Comment: Thanks for advice @ nonsensickle.I will follow those instructions from next question....

Comment: There is no reason to prefer 1.9.5. Use the current release.